# É correto implementar teste unitário na model no contexto da linguagem Python?

Tags: python, testes, testes-de-unidade

Em algumas linguagens não é adequado. Gostaria de saber se em python é diferente. Grata.

Comment: Qual model? Por que seria errado?

Comment: Não acredito que seja "errado" em alguma linguagem, apenas uma decisão de paradigma. Dê uma olhada neste documento:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

Comment: Poderia postar alguma referência em que fale que é errado? Ou o contexto em que está se embasando?

Comment: Eu creio que sem [edit] e colocar o contexto de onde tirou que em algumas linguagens é errado ou certo, e quais critérios usados, a pergunta não tem como levar a uma resposta objetiva, apenas discussões difusas sobre o assunto (o que não cabe no nosso modelo). Sugeriria contextualizar melhor, com base em [ask] e no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Não acredito que seja "errado" em alguma linguagem, apenas uma decisão de paradigma.

Em Python:

> O framework [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) foi originalmente inspirado no JUnit e é parecido com a maioria dos frameworks de teste unitário em outras linguagens. Ele suporta a automação de teste, compartilhamento de código de inicialização e interrupção para testes, agregação de testes e independência dos testes do framework de relatórios.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html